# hadoop dfs used 100% with little data

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera-cdh

Recently I format namenode to hdfs   `(hadoop namenode format )`  ,but  when  I start the hdfs  it couldn't  upload anydata  to `HDFS`   then  I delete the datanode directory  to make sure the have the same  namespace .

but when I `hdfs dfsadmin -report`  it has a strange things

```
Live datanodes (3):

Name: 192.168.0.30:50010 (hadoop1)
Hostname: hadoop1
Rack: /default
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 0 (0 B)
DFS Used: 8192 (8 KB)
Non DFS Used: 0 (0 B)
DFS Remaining: 0 (0 B)
DFS Used%: 100.00%
DFS Remaining%: 0.00%
Configured Cache Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used: 0 (0 B)
Cache Remaining: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used%: 100.00%
Cache Remaining%: 0.00%
Xceivers: 2
Last contact: Thu Mar 22 14:10:41 CST 2018
```

all the  datanodes `dfs used 100%  &  remining 0%`

But it also  have available interspace on the disk,

```
[root@hadoop1 nn]# df -h /dfs/
Filesystem           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/cl-root   70G   55G   16G  78% /
```

when I open the namenode webpage  the capacity is zero
[image]

Any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: The capacity of cluster comes from datanodes in it. What do you mean by you deleted datanode directory?

Comment: `Configured Capacity: 0 (0 B)`... That's your actual problem